# Is it possible to make an editable select in blueprintjs?

Tags: reactjs, blueprintjs

I've been playing a bit with it and haven't found the way to do it. Here is a link to the relevant part of the documentation: 
http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#components.forms.select

The desired functionality is like the one we can find in this framework:
http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/
but for design reasons I want to avoid mixing different UI frameworks.

If it is not possible, is there any way to style react-select so that it looks like a blueprintjs select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, we do not *currently* support such a thing, but we're planning to in the near future! `Dropdown` and `Typeahead` are **literally next** on our components list. You can follow the discussion here: https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/118.